# Why does the value of the random bound reset when I change the scene?

Tags: java, javafx, return-value

I'm stuck on a bug for quite a while. I have two classes in JavaFX (Controller and Guessing Game). In the Controller I have a slider in scene 3 in the Settings menu. I grab the value of the slider when the user moves it and set this value to the bound of a random number. But when I switch back to the Menu and then to scene 2 the value of the bound goes back to the startervalue 100. The issue must be something between scene 1 to 2. Does anybody know why the value resets back to 100 if I had changed it with the slider to another value? Thx

Controller:

```
public class Controller {

    GuessingGame guessingGame = new GuessingGame();;

    @FXML
    private TextField textfield;
    @FXML
    private Label countText;
    public Label notification;
    public Label textBetween;
    @FXML
    public Slider sliderSettings;

    private int currentNumber;

    public void clickedOnExit() {
        System.exit(1);
    }

    ;

    public void clickedOnSettings() {
        Main.pStage.setScene(Main.scene3);
    }

    ;

    public void clickedOnPlay() {
        Main.pStage.setScene(Main.scene2);                          //Beim wechsel zu szene 2 wird der wert wieder auf 100 gesetzt
        System.out.println(guessingGame.getRandomBound());
    }

    ;

    public void clickedBackToMenu() {
        Main.pStage.setScene(Main.scene1);
    }

    ;

    public void clickedBackToMenuSettings() {
        Main.pStage.setScene(Main.scene1);
    }


    //SLIDER
    public void sliderSetValue() {
        guessingGame.setRandomBound((int) sliderSettings.getValue());
        System.out.println(guessingGame.getRandomBound());
    }

    ;

    public void enteredTextfield() {

        currentNumber = Integer.parseInt(textfield.getText());

        GuessingGame.Result checkNumber;

        //Setzt
        checkNumber = guessingGame.evaluateEnteredNumber(currentNumber);

        if (checkNumber == GuessingGame.Result.HIGHER) {
            notification.setText("HIGHER");
        }
        ;
        if (checkNumber == GuessingGame.Result.LOWER) {
            notification.setText("LOWER");
        }
        ;
        if (checkNumber == GuessingGame.Result.EQUALS) {
            notification.setText("YOU GOT IT!");
            textBetween.setText("Congratulations! The number was: " + guessingGame.getNumber());
        }
        ;
        textfield.clear();
        countText.setText("" + guessingGame.getCounter());  //Gibts ihr eine bessere Lösung?
    }
}
```

Guessing Game:

```
import java.util.Random;

public class GuessingGame {

    Random rand = new Random();

    private int number;
    private int counter;
    //Variable die maxhöhe der Zufallszahl am Anfang auf 100 Stand
    private int randomBound = 100;

    public enum Result {
        EQUALS, HIGHER, LOWER
    }

    //Random number muss noch implementiert werden, sodass sie im Bound steht
    public GuessingGame() {
        getNumberToGuess();             //Konstruktor
    }

    public int getNumberToGuess() {
        this.number = rand.nextInt(randomBound);                 //im bound muss der wert vom slide sein
        return number;
    }

    //Methode für das Spielgeschehen gibt Das Ergebnis wieder obs höher/tiefer/gleich ist
    public Result evaluateEnteredNumber(int enteredNumber) {
        Result result;

        counter++;

        if (number > enteredNumber) {
            result = Result.HIGHER;
        } else if (number < enteredNumber) {
            result = Result.LOWER;
        } else {
            result = Result.EQUALS;
        }
        return result;
    }


    //----------------------------------------------------//
    //Getter und Setter//

    //Setter und Getter für die Zufallszahl
    public void setNumber(int  newNumber) {
        this.number = newNumber;
    }
    public int getNumber() {
        return number;
    }
    //Setter und Getter für den Versuchzähler
    public void setCounter(int newCounter) {
        this.counter = newCounter;
    }
    public int getCounter() {
        return counter;
    }
    //Setter und Getter für Die maxhöhe der Zufallszahl
    public void setRandomBound(int newRandomBound) {
        this.randomBound = newRandomBound;
    }
    public int getRandomBound() {
        return randomBound;
    }
}
```

Scene 1:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import javafx.scene.control.Button?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.Label?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.AnchorPane?>
<?import javafx.scene.text.Font?>


<AnchorPane prefHeight="400.0" prefWidth="600.0" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/11.0.1" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" fx:controller="sample.Controller">
   <children>
      <Button fx:id="exitButton" layoutX="505.0" layoutY="349.0" mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="#clickedOnExit" prefHeight="37.0" prefWidth="81.0" text="Exit" />
      <Button fx:id="playButton" layoutX="237.0" layoutY="163.0" mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="#clickedOnPlay" prefHeight="37.0" prefWidth="126.0" text="Play" />
      <Button fx:id="settingsButton" layoutX="237.0" layoutY="213.0" mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="#clickedOnSettings" prefHeight="37.0" prefWidth="126.0" text="Settings" />
      <Label layoutX="66.0" layoutY="14.0" prefHeight="117.0" prefWidth="469.0" text="GUESSING GAME">
         <font>
            <Font name="Arial Black" size="49.0" />
         </font>
      </Label>
   </children>
</AnchorPane>
```

Scene 2:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import javafx.scene.control.Button?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.Label?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.TextField?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.AnchorPane?>
<?import javafx.scene.text.Font?>

<AnchorPane maxHeight="-Infinity" maxWidth="-Infinity" minHeight="-Infinity" minWidth="-Infinity" prefHeight="400.0" prefWidth="600.0" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/11.0.1" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" fx:controller="sample.Controller">
   <children>
      <Label layoutX="72.0" prefHeight="20.0" prefWidth="457.0" text="GUESSING GAME">
         <font>
            <Font name="Arial Black" size="48.0" />
         </font>
      </Label>
      <Label layoutX="72.0" layoutY="187.0" text="Your guess:">
         <font>
            <Font name="Arial" size="22.0" />
         </font>
      </Label>
      <Label layoutX="395.0" layoutY="187.0" text="Attempts:">
         <font>
            <Font name="Arial" size="22.0" />
         </font>
      </Label>
      <TextField fx:id="textfield" layoutX="197.0" layoutY="188.0" onAction="#enteredTextfield" prefHeight="25.0" prefWidth="66.0" />
      <Label fx:id="countText" layoutX="496.0" layoutY="188.0" text="0">
         <font>
            <Font name="Arial" size="22.0" />
         </font>
      </Label>
      <Label layoutX="48.0" layoutY="71.0" text="My number is a random number up to 100! Try to guess it!">
         <font>
            <Font name="Arial Black" size="16.0" />
         </font>
      </Label>
      <Label fx:id="notification" layoutX="221.0" layoutY="120.0" text="Type a number!">
         <font>
            <Font name="Arial Black" size="22.0" />
         </font>
      </Label>
      <Label fx:id="textBetween" layoutX="72.0" layoutY="272.0" prefHeight="26.0" prefWidth="356.0" text="Your number is between 0 and 100">
         <font>
            <Font name="Arial Black" size="17.0" />
         </font>
      </Label>
      <Button fx:id="backToMenu" layoutX="485.0" layoutY="361.0" mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="#clickedBackToMenu" text="Back to Menu" />
   </children>
</AnchorPane>
```

Scene 3:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import javafx.scene.control.Button?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.Label?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.Slider?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.AnchorPane?>
<?import javafx.scene.text.Font?>

<AnchorPane maxHeight="-Infinity" maxWidth="-Infinity" minHeight="-Infinity" minWidth="-Infinity" prefHeight="400.0" prefWidth="600.0" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/11.0.1" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" fx:controller="sample.Controller">
   <children>
      <Slider fx:id="sliderSettings" layoutY="200.0" max="1000.0" minorTickCount="4" onMouseReleased="#sliderSetValue" prefHeight="38.0" prefWidth="592.0" showTickLabels="true" showTickMarks="true" snapToTicks="true" value="100.0" />
      <Label layoutX="4.0" layoutY="117.0" prefHeight="47.0" prefWidth="592.0" text="How High can the number you want to guess be?">
         <font>
            <Font name="Arial Black" size="22.0" />
         </font>
      </Label>
      <Button fx:id="backToMenuSettings" layoutX="497.0" layoutY="361.0" mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="#clickedBackToMenuSettings" text="Back to Menu" />
   </children>
</AnchorPane>
```

Main:

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader;
import javafx.scene.Parent;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class Main extends Application {
    public static Stage pStage;

    public static Parent root1;
    public static Parent root2;
    public static Parent root3;

    public static Scene scene1;
    public static Scene scene2;
    public static Scene scene3;

    public Main() {
    }

    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) throws Exception {

        pStage = stage;

        root1 = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("scene1.fxml"));
        root2 = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("scene2.fxml"));
        root3 = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("scene3.fxml"));


        scene1 = new Scene(root1);
        scene2 = new Scene(root2);
        scene3 = new Scene(root3);

        stage.setScene(scene1);
        stage.show();

    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

Sorry that the nodes are in German. They are for me to figure out why that happens but it should be in the change of the scenes. THX for any help!

Comment: You are asking people to debug your code but you haven't provided a [mcve]. I suggest you [edit] your question and at least post the contents of your FXML file.

Comment: Sure I will....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was just, that I initialized the Object at the beginning and in every controller a new one. So I didn't handle with the same, so the value got lost.